# Weird VS2010 debugger error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++

I have a class(only one!), written in C++ where I can't use the debugger. For "this" I have only its address and when I expand it I have as member only __vfptr with value 0x00000000. I can see function parameters in the debugger when I call function from the class, but I can't see any member variables. Class name is Stream, it doesn't have virtual functions. It has many Read/Write overloaded functions for different data types. Do you have any idea why I have this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: post code, not much we can do otherwise.

Comment: are you building in debug mode with no optimizations?

Comment: Probably the object you are trying to see was corrupted by some code earlier. Try to check your code by Application Verifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed class name from Stream to MemoryStream and now debugger works. Thanks for help!