# VS2010 debugger: in a class, 'this' is not showing it's members. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm trying to debug a C++ class. It's a class that gets SWIGged for Python, then I attach debugger to python.exe. No problems there. Breakpoints are hit fine.

But in the 'Locals' window 'this' is completely empty apart from its _vfptr (which does not look right either, just values, no function names). 'this' should have a few member variables!

Function parameters are showing fine. Functions appear to, well, function properly.

Trying to 'Watch' or 'Quickwatch' a variable from the editor window gives 'inaccessible!'.

What foul Visual Studio crime have I committed? This was working fine earlier on!

Comment: Ooops. (It's my first time!) I just duped this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224396/weird-vs2010-debugger-error